# Trouble when searched with get method in PHP/MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I have some troubles about searching with get method.

My code in result.php **(View)**:

```
<form action="doResult" method="get">
<input type="text" name="search_text" placeholder="Search..." id="search_text" autocomplete="off" tabindex="1">
<button type="submit" class="ui secondary basic button" name="submit">
<a><i class="search link icon" id="search-icon"></i>Search<a>
</button>
</form>
```

and in controller:

```
public function doResult()
        {
            $data = $this->model('cfs_model');
            if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
            {   
                $search = addslashes($_GET['search_text']);
                if(empty($search))
                {
                    $content = '<div class="ui black segment">Not Found In Data !</div>';
                    $result_array = array('error' => $content);
                }
                else
                {
                    $result = $data->getResultStore($search,$this->total_store_in_onepage);
                    $page = $data->totalResultStore($search,$this->total_store_in_onepage);
                    if($result == FALSE || $page == FALSE)
                    {
                        $content = '<div class="ui black segment">Not Found In Data !</div>';
                        $result_array = array('error' => $content);
                    }
                    else {
                        $result_array = array('store' => $result,
                                    'page' => $page,
                                    'search' => $search);
                    }
                }
                $this->view('home/result',$result_array);
            }   
        }
```

But when i **searched many times in searching input**, *my controller will return result.html with url is mybase_url/home/result.html* and i don't know why !. I have checked in my folder and my controller code already, but i can't find where i call "result.html" from controller and why it doesn't active my controller when call result ? in this url. I think this bug comes from method[get], doesn't it ?. Please help me answer ! Tks

Comment: You are calling /home/result in this line $this->view('home/result',$result_array);

Comment: yes, i know ! But my file is result.php, not result.html. I don't know the reason when i searched continuously at many times. In 1,2 times it active, but the next times, it will return home/result.html @nicolascolman

Comment: Do you have any js code in the view?

Comment: @nicolascolman tks, you saved my life :'(... when i build front-end, i have to add 1 script to check user input on my search and i forgot removing it when started back-end. Another things: i have some trouble with my php mailer. Can u help me fix that :'( !